# PowerBi JavaScript dashboard embedConfiguration

Tags: javascript, embed, powerbi

I would like to embed my PowerBi Dashboard into an HTML file using JavaScript from the sample code from [this GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript). The error that I am getting is:

> Unable to get property 'models' of undefined or null reference

Am I missing a `.js` file that needs to be added to the head section?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.js"></script>`
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      // Get models. models contains enums that can be used.
      var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;
      var embedConfiguration = {
        type: 'dashboard',
        id: 'dashboardid',
        embedUrl: 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed',
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
        accessToken: 'TokenKey'
      };
      var $dashboardContainer = $('#embedContainer');
      var dashboard = powerbi.embed($dashboardContainer.get(0), embedConfiguration);
        });
  </script>
</head >
  <body>
    <div id="dashboardContainer"></div>
  </body >
</html >
```

Comment: Have you tried to include PowerBi js library? After that i think you may need d3. also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include [**ECMAScript 6**](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features) (ES6):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.3/es6-shim.js"></script>
```

You'll also need to load the actual [**PowerBi**](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/) library, along with any necessary JS files, since it doesn't appear that you are already doing so, at least in the code you provided.

You're also assigning the variable, `$dashboardContainer`, the value of `$('#embedContainer')` which isn't an element in the HTML you provided. You used the **ID** of `#dashboardContainer` in your HTML.

Comment: Is this the PowerBi library [github site](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript) do I need the files in the v2-demo/scripts/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with,

```js
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/master/dist/powerbi.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried the raw.githubusercontent API but still getting the SCRIPT5009: 'models' is undefined, is this the correct way to call the API.      var embedConfiguration = {
                type: 'dashboard',
                id: 'DashboardID',
                embedUrl: 'https://app.powerbi.com/dashboardEmbed',
                tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
                accessToken: 'TokenKey'
            };

            var $dashboardContainer = $('#embedContainer');
            var dashboard = powerbi.embed($dashboardContainer.get(0), embedConfiguration);